# SASS: Direct Descendent rule?

Tags: css, sass

How do I represent a direct descendent CSS rule in SASS?

Ex.

```
body > div { ... }
```

Couldn't seem to find it in the docs: http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass and combined child selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345763/sass-and-combined-child-selector)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should just be able to

```
body
  >div
    property:value
```

You may have to escape the `>` with a backslash `\`.

Comment: Note: no space between `>` and `div`. I thought sass couldn't do this for so long because I like whitespace.

Comment: I always did `& > div`, but I didn't like it because it looked too messy. This is a lot cleaner, though not perfect, but that's not your fault, of course. Thanks!

Comment: i think this should be more visible somewhere in the documentation

Comment: I'm trying it with whitespace and it seems to work (though I am doing it through codeacademy's UI). Like this: `  > .nested_class `