# CSS's child selector not working in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I want to apply a style to the immediate child `<a>` tag of and element.

In normal CSS I would use something like:

```
.card > a {
 color: red;
}
```

But in Sass I cannot get this or any of the following combinations to work.

In my .scss file I've tried:

```
.card > a {
 color: red;
}

.card & > a {
 color: red;
}

.card {
  > a {
     color: red;
    }
}

.card {
  & > a {
   color: red;
  }
}
```

But none of these works. No errors are showing in the compiler either.

Would anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SASS: Direct Descendent rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075257/sass-direct-descendent-rule)

Comment: Have you tried with `& >div` (without white space between `>` and `div`)?

Comment: Since your first example is exactly the same as the CSS, there is no reason it would not work. A likely reason is that you are not compiling your SASS properly, or the compiled file is not being brought into your application properly. Your second example is invalid syntax. Either the third or fourth should work fine. PS. Why are you trying to use SASS?

Answer (score 0):

This works: because the & concatenates from .card

```
.card {
  &>a {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as what the OP said **didn't** work. Furthermore, the `&` is unnecessary.

Comment: yes, the & is useless in this case and I should have omitted it. And yes, I should have asked the OP to check some syntax since what he was trying, should have worked (other than the invalid example of course)